# autohotkey: 3 keys pressed together = hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

language: Autohotkey on Win7

"Shift" plus "right mouse button" plus "mouse wheel up"

I want my hotkey to be holding those three keys simultaneously. I have tried the following without any success

```
+ & rbutton & wheelup:: 
send 6

+rbutton & wheelup::
send 6


shift & rbutton & wheelup::
send 6
```

I always get an error when I try to make this hotkey does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a newbie but I'll try and help =].

It doesn't seem to work when you use a modifier key with two mouse buttons, so this is a way that *kind of* works:

```
+WheelUp::
KeyWait, RButton, D    ; Waits for RButton to be pressed down.
MsgBox, This works!
Return
```

The problem is it clicks (or releases) the right mouse button once the hotkey has run. If you instead put it like so:

```
+RButton::
KeyWait, WheelUp, D
```

There will be another problem in that it will work fine for the **first** use of the hotkey, it will from then on work with only Shift + Right Mouse Button, because it's already waited for WheelUp to be pressed down (or rather scrolled up).

I mucked around for a little bit with GetKeyState and the like but still being new I can't find a way around it xD. These may be sufficient for what you need for now, otherwise better to wait for someone more knowledgeable to post.

Comment: goal is to HOLD the shift+rbutton and be able to spam the mwheel. ideally.

Answer (score 1):

With the information from your comment (hold Shift+right and spam WheelUp) following solution works fine. Use Shift + WheelUp and check if the right mosue button is down.

```
+WheelUp::
    if (GetKeyState("RButton", "P"))
        send 6
    else
        send +{WheelUp}
return
```

You could remove the else part and add a **~** modifier, but then Shift + WheelUp will be catched and blocked by AHK even if you dont press the right mouse button.